# AudioKit: How to switch filter types when using AKOperationEffect?

Tags: ios, swift, audiokit

Lets say I use a moog filter for lowpass like the following, but also wat to switch mode to some highpass filter, too.

```
class FilterSection: AKNode, AKInput {
...
init(_ input: AKNode) {

    output = AKOperationEffect(input) { input, parameters in

        return input.moogLadderFilter(
            cutoffFrequency: parameters[0],
            resonance: parameters[1]
        )
    }

    super.init()
    self.initFilterParameters()
    output.parameters = parameters
    self.avAudioNode = output.avAudioNode
}
...
}
```

How could I add the feature to switch between this and another filter type within the same class?

Is it possible, or do I have to use some construct like

```
    filterSection1 = FilterSection1(generators)
    filterSection2 = FilterSection2(filterSection1)
    filterSection1.output.start()
    filterSection2.output.stop()
```

and the switch between types like

```
    filterSection1.output.stop()
    filterSection2.output.start()
```

which I want to avoid?
thnx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't switch filter types, but you can run them in parallel, mix them, and then change the mix from one to the other, with the added benefit of being able to blend or morph between the two.

Comment: Operations are not really meant for optimizing the CPU, but for sketching out what you need. Once you've found your sound, and want to work on efficiency, then you might want to pop down to the C++ level or something.

Comment: unfortunately this is not my domain yet